# Custom DjangoModelPermissions not being applied

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that allows a user to be a member of multiple Organizations.

```
from django.conf import settings
from app.shared.models import BaseModel

class Organization(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class OrganizationMember(BaseModel):
    ROLE_OPTIONS = (
        (OrganizationMemberRole.admin.value, _('Admin')),
        (OrganizationMemberRole.editor.value, _('Editor')),
        (OrganizationMemberRole.view.value, _('View Only')),
    )

    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        related_name='members',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='user_role',
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
    )
```

I've also got a custom user model with a property that generates a list of Organization IDs for that user

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

from .managers import CustomUserManager


class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def user_organization_ids(self):
        """ 
        Returns a list of Organization IDs. Converts UUID to str 
        """

        user_orgs_qs = self.user_role.all().values_list('organization_id', flat=True)
        return [str(i) for i in user_orgs_qs]
```

There are other models in the database that will have a relationship with an Organization. For example, Widget

```
from app.shared.models import BaseModel

class Widget(BaseModel):

    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I want to restrict CRUD operations based on OrganizationMember relationships.

So, a user should only be able to perform CRUD operations on Widget if they are a member of the Organization.

I've created

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions


class OrganizationPermission(DjangoModelPermissions):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return hasattr(obj, 'organization_id') and obj.organization_id is not None and obj.organization_id in request.user.user_organization_ids
```

and my views:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import Widget
from .serializers import WidgetSerializer
from app.shared.permissions import OrganizationPermission


class WidgetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = WidgetSerializer
    permission_classes = (OrganizationPermission, IsAuthenticated)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Widget.objects.filter(organization_id=self.kwargs['organization_id'])
```

but this does not seem to work; in my tests I can see Widgets in organizations that my user does not belong to, and no errors are returned.

Any suggestions on how to modify my DjangoModelPermission ?

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the logic in your has_object_permission is not working as intended. The most likely issue is this line:

```
obj.organization_id in request.user.user_organization_ids
```

Here, obj.organization_id is expected to be a string (as the user_organization_ids returns a list of strings), but Django automatically treats ForeignKey ids as integers or UUIDs (if using a UUID field). So you should convert the organization id to string before comparing it.

Your has_object_permission function should look like this:

```
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    return hasattr(obj, 'organization') and str(obj.organization_id) in request.user.user_organization_ids
```

However, it's also possible the issue lies in how you're applying these permissions in your views. You should add the OrganizationPermission class to the permission_classes attribute of your view. Here is an example:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .models import Widget
from .permissions import OrganizationPermission

class WidgetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Widget.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (OrganizationPermission,)
    # other attributes...
```

If you've already done this, it's worth double-checking the rest of your view logic. Also, ensure that your tests are properly set up and are correctly emulating the desired permissions scenario.

One final note is that your OrganizationMember model should have a role field to utilize ROLE_OPTIONS you've defined:

```
class OrganizationMember(BaseModel):
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROLE_OPTIONS)
    # other fields...
```

If you'd like to further restrict the operations based on the role (admin, editor, viewer), you could add this to your permission checks in the has_object_permission method.

Comment: hi - thanks for your reply. I've updated my post with my current view, which implements permissions_classes as you've suggested. That still does not work